# Issue adding instance to the database with SQLAlchemy specifying the foreign key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two model dataclasses in SQLAlchemy, a `Parent` and a `Child`. The `Child` has a foreign key relationship to the `Parent` like so:

```
@dataclass
class Child:
    parent_code: str = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={
            "sa": Column(
                String,
                ForeignKey(Parent.code),
            ),
            "desc": "Type code",
        },
    )
    parent: Parent = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={"sa": relationship(Parent)},
    )
```

When I create a new child e.g. `child = Child(parent_code="code")` the foreign key value is present until session is committed and then it's cleared i.e. `child.parent_code` is `None`. I would have thought that `child.parent_code` would be persisted, `child.parent` would be null before committing and return the `Parent` instance after committing.

If I set the relationship like `child = Child(parent=ParentInstance)`, that works fine. Or if I remove the `parent` relationship from the `Child` class and just have `parent_code` it works fine. Not sure what I'm missing.

Here's a full working demo:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import ClassVar

from sqlalchemy.schema import DropTable, Identity
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry, relationship, Session
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from cesium.api.dependencies import get_engine


@compiles(DropTable, "postgresql")
def _compile_drop_table(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    return compiler.visit_drop_table(element) + " CASCADE"


mapper_registry = registry()
engine = get_engine()

# mapper_registry.metadata.clear()
mapper_registry.metadata.reflect(engine)
mapper_registry.metadata.drop_all(engine)


@mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class Parent:
    __tablename__: ClassVar[str] = "Parent"

    code = Column("code", String, primary_key=True)
    value = Column("value", String, nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, code, value):
        self.code = code
        self.value = value


@mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class Child:
    __tablename__: ClassVar[str] = "Child"
    __sa_dataclass_metadata_key__: ClassVar[str] = "sa"

    id: int = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(Integer, Identity(), primary_key=True)})
    parent_code: str = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={
            "sa": Column(
                String,
                ForeignKey(Parent.code),
            ),
        },
    )
    parent: Parent = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={"sa": relationship(Parent)},
    )


mapper_registry.metadata.create_all(engine)


with Session(engine) as session:
    # Add test parent instance
    value = Parent(code="w", value="www")
    session.add(value)
    session.commit()

    # Create child specifying parent_code foreign key
    child = Child(parent_code="w")
    session.add(child)
    print("Before commit: parent_code =", child.parent_code)

    session.commit()

    print("Commited: parent_code =", child.parent_code)
```

Comment: Is it safe to mix dataclasses with SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Yeah, they added support pretty recently in [version 1.4](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_styles.html#declarative-mapping-with-dataclasses-and-attrs). I wasn't sure if that was what was causing issues though.